# Routing with Data using Activated Route

Tags: angular, routes, ionic2

In this `console.log(this.sorder)` is printed where `sorder` comes from another component but it is not assignable to `this.filter={sort_order:this.sorder}` which is using in my template in two way binding and in if part it is working perfectly

```ts
   import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
   import {Http,Response,Headers} from "@angular/http";
   import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
    selector: 'basic-tables',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styles: [require('./filter_add.scss')],
    template: require('./filter_add.html')
    })

    export class FilterAdd {
    public filter;
    public filter_data;
    public filter_added:boolean = false;
    private headers: Headers;
    public sorder:string;
    public fname:string;
    private addFilter_url = 'http://localhost:4545/api/addFilter';

    constructor(private http:Http,private route:ActivatedRoute) {
    route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.sorder = params['sort_order'];
      this.fname = params['name'];
    });

    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

    // the question is about this part of the code:
    if(this.sorder==undefined  && this.fname==undefined) {
      this.filter = {
        sort_order: '11',
        filter_group_name: '1234'
      }
    }
    else{
      console.log(this.sorder);
      this.filter = {
        sort_order: this.sorder,
        filter_group_name: this.fname
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more code. Ideally a Plunker that allows to reproduce.

Comment: I don't really used tio plunkar but i give u full code here

Comment: Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular2 TS template. Just click the "New" button.

Comment: if pointer goes to if part it is working properly but if goes to else part then sort_order and filter_group_name values is blank

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/FlyYFYTjJVDuwpvAjllT?p=preview plunkar